# Access container page of a component in .net based CT

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are developing a .net based CT based on Broker query Mechanism (filter):

```
ComponentPresentationAssembler  cpAssembler = new ComponentPresentationAssembler(Page ID,Page object);
```

In order to pass the page ID, I need to get the access of page on which the component is present.
How can I access the page from package? Since this a CT, a component object would be available in page and not a page object.
Tried the following piece of code, but without success:

```
string pageURI = _package.GetValue("Page.ID");
Page objPage = (Page)_engine.GetSession().GetObject(pageURI);
```

This is not working as there is no page object. What are the alternatives so that we can access the parent page of component from CT?

Comment: What about the approach Mihai suggests here: http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/04/passing-pageuri-to-dcp-for-dynamic.html

Comment: Wrong link, I meant THIS one: http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/passing_the_pageURI_to_a_DCP_for_dynamic_linking.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address this I created an AddPageToComponentPresentation TBB. Here's the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using Tridion.ContentManager;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Templating;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly;

namespace Tridion.Extensions.ContentManager.Templating {
    [TcmTemplateTitle("Add Page To ComponentPresentation")]
    class AddPageToComponentPresentation : TemplateBase {
        public override void Transform(Engine engine, Package package) {
            if (engine.PublishingContext.RenderContext.ContextItem != null) {
                Item pageItem = package.CreateTridionItem(ContentType.Page, engine.PublishingContext.RenderContext.ContextItem.Id);
                package.PushItem("Page", pageItem);
                Logger.Debug("Page Item added to Package");
            } else {
                Logger.Debug("No Context Item found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but now you have to be careful with all other TBBs, as it is fairly common to determine if a TBB is running in a Component Template context by checking if there is a Page object available in the package, the absence of it usually tells you you are in a CT while the existence could then tell you you are in a PT.

Comment: I never saw that check myself (not that that's indicative of anything) but it would have influence in that situation. I guess an option would be to change the name of the Item that get's created. "ContextPage" instead maybe.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot Jeremy.
I tried this code, but was not able to use the interface **TemplateBase**

With hints from your code, I tried

```
Page page = _engine.PublishingContext.RenderContext.ContextItem as Page;
```

and this worked well. Also I could get publication object as:

```
Publication pub = (Publication)page.ContextRepository;
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: The TemplateBase interface is part of the templating base project: http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/templatingbase.aspx

Comment: Oops, sorry. I guess, in the absence of the TemplateBase class that should probably be ITemplate instead ;)